# How to Scan for conditional matching string and loop if matched

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I have 2 file,Big and small with ';' delimited.

```
old_file
    Apple;aaa@abc.com
    Banana;bbb@abc.com
    carrot;ccc@abc.com


new File  
Banana;new@abc.com
```

I am creating a shell script that check new file data and send email, after that it scans remaining
un-matching data in big file and send email respectively.(for matched value it should take new email)

My code

---

```
#Variables
name_old=`awk -F ";" '{print $1} {$temp}`; 
email_old=`awk -F ";" '{print $2} {$temp}`;
name_new=`cat 'smallfile' | awk -F ";" '{print $1}'`;
email_new=`cat 'smallfile' | awk -F ";" '{print $2}'`;


///
if #grep -wq $name_new <<< $name_old
[[ "$name_new" == "$name_old" ]]
then
echo "store the matched value email in a variable"
else
echo "store the unmatched value email in a variable"
fi  



sample Output can be stored in a variable.
aaa@abc.com  
new@abc.com--->matching record so updated email  
ccc@abc.com
```

Can someone pls review and update if anything is going wrong?
I am new to shell scripting but am trying :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` is more suitable tool for this.

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"} NR==FNR {map[$1]=$2; next} $1 in map {$2=map[$1]} 1' newfile oldfile

Apple;aaa@abc.com
Banana;new@abc.com
carrot;ccc@abc.com
```

Comment: What are variables here..could you please explain your solution.

Comment: This is to generate same output as in your `sample Output`. You can read some basic awk tutprial.

Comment: Can I use variables instead of file?

Comment: What does these variables contain? You already have data in files so why not use directly from file?

Comment: Those files are to set an example for understanding.I have already extracted the required data in variables(in my code) so only I need to loop in so that matching data will have updated email id and unmatched data will used original id.

Comment: I have edited my output,also variables are already extracted we just need to define a logic/loop/map pls review my code to understand.Thanks.

Comment: Still there is just pseudo code not real code. How are files being read? How are those 4 variables being populated etc is not clear from question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233085/discussion-between-pikun95-and-anubhava).

Comment: I have extracted those using awk command.so All data are inplaced in variables.we only need to match it and get the updated email to store in a variable sir.

Comment: ok please show your awk command in question not the pseudo code